# Detect memory overwrites with XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Is there any way to detect the following scenario which as far as I know overwrite memory in bad places? Or any other which tries to set an NSDictionary for an NSString or anything like that?

`int a[6];
a[6] = 8`

Also just to be sure I get a lot of EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS in my app and from what I've seen these are caused by memory overwrites. Is there any other way to debug this crashes because they don't happen on my devices/simulator but rather for users in certain situations which I can't replicate.

Comment: Well, you could compile with -Weverything -Werror or at least -Wall -Werror. Then you could give the static analyzer a try. And then there is the all new address sanitizer. Give those a try :) (or use Swift :D)

Answer (score 1):

There is!

Have a look in the Options pane of Xcode's scheme editor.   You can enable malloc scribble, which will help somewhat.   What you probably want, though, are guard pages.   Basically, it creates a non-accessible page of memory at the beginning or the end of an allocation.  This causes an access crash if you try to read from or write to outside the bounds of your allocation.

Details here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html

Comment: Hey, I've tried with malloc guard and I run out of memory while debugging.

Comment: That'll happen.  It explodes memory use.  you need a fairly short reproducible set of steps.